# Start playback on given millisecond with node-lame and speaker

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, mp3, lame

I'm trying to use [node-lame](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lame) and [speaker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/speaker) to play mp3 files on my pc using node (no browser), I'm trying to choose a certain millisecond to begin playback:

My code (similar to given examples):

```
function play(filename) {
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
    this.speaker = new Speaker();
    stream.pipe(lame.Decoder()).pipe(this.speaker); 
}
```

I would like my function to support the following input:

```
function play(filename, startingTime) { // startingTime in milliseconds
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I'm looking for the exact same thing...

Comment: @PhilippJardas sadly, no

Comment: For my understanding, you need to convert the time (offset), to a byte offset, where to start to read the file. For example, 1s = 1byte, if you want to skip 10secs, skip the first 10 bytes of the file, and start with reading from the 11 byte.